# Is there a term for when the music of a song seems to be 'layered ontop' of the vocals?

Tags: voice, metal

I used to get this impression from Rammstein's 'Heirate Mich'. Normally when I listen to music, it sounds like the vocals are ontop of the music (if that makes sense). With that song though, it sounded like part of the music was ontop of the vocals instead. I kinda liked the effect, even though it didn't last.

More recently, I seem to have encountered this effect in the songs of a short-lived metal group called 'wraith'.

Is this just my perception playing tricks on me, or is this a real phenomenon with a name?

Comment: Are those vocals ever sung without the background music?

Comment: What do you mean by "on top of": 'louder than' or 'at a higher pitch than'? I'm hearing what Laurence is hearing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the terms you want to use are *track* or *channel*, *level*, *balance*, and *mix*.

In a recording you can have multiple *tracks* for instruments. In live performance they are called *channels*. Well, I suppose you have channels for both recordings and live - it's just the electronic path - the *track* would be the channel's data recorded to some media.

The track/channel's volume can then be controlled to set its *level*.

The relative levels between tracks is called *balance*.

The balance of levels is set for the final *mix*.

You could then say the vocal level is low in the mix. If you thought it was *too low*, you could then say the balance isn't right, etc. etc.

I don't know of a special term for putting the vocal level a bit low in the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hearing a low-pitched singer with some higher notes in the instruments.   A very common orchestration technique - else the violin players need not show up for any opera featuring a bass singer!

No particular name for this I think, except describing it in plain English.